UE 5.4 crashes when entering play mode with error message Assertion failed: !RasterizerPass.ClusterComputeShader.IsNull()
crash report
I've been using UE 5.3 for my project pretty much for as long as 5.3 has been out and never had this crash message appear. I wanted to upgrade to 5.4 for the performance gains, but unfortunatelly more than half the time I try to enter play mode the engine crashes and gives me this message. Anyone know's what might be the cause of this?
I don't really know what I can try to do to find a solution. I haven't changed anything in my project yet after switching to 5.4
edit: so far it seems that nanite tesselation is what causes this crash, but I still have no idea how to fix this

I can totally relate to what you're experiencing. I've encountered a very similar issue after upgrading to UE 5.4.2 and enabling tessellation, as well as converting my landscape to Nanite. I'm also facing frequent crashes with a similar error message.
In my case, turning off Nanite tessellation resolves the issue, but like you, I would prefer not to disable this feature. I've shared my detailed crash report and some of my findings in this forum post: Frequent crashes with Nanite tessellation in UE 5.4.2.
Maybe we can exchange experiences and work together to find a solution? If you have any additional insights or have managed to figure out anything else, please let me know! I'd be happy to share my findings as well.

EDIT: Actually, I've found a solution to this problem! After extensive testing and troubleshooting, I discovered that the crashes were caused by a specific shader error in my project. I've shared detailed steps and insights in my latest forum post on Unreal Forums. The issue was related to certain tree materials that had a shader error, specifically "[SM6] Expression is part of a cycle. Please make sure the material graph is acyclic." Fixing this error resolved the crashes completely.
If you're interested in the exact steps I took and the script I used to detect such errors, you can find all the information in my detailed post on Unreal Forums. It might help you solve your issue as well!

So far, I ignored the issue and kept working in Unreal Engine 5.3. I'm hoping that maybe this gets fixed in a future 5.4 release. If I figure something out, I'll definitely let you know :)

Take a peek at my post again, I have a proposition of a solution, hope it will help! :)

Thanks for letting me know, I'm really happy that you managed to resolve this problem :) Unfortunately, I don't have any errors in my project. I have one material that uses nanite tessellation, that is pretty basic, and even if I try to open a new empty scene that has one model with this tessellation material applied, there is a good chance I will get a crash :/

I discovered another issue today: when I tried using RVT caching for my landscape while also caching Displacement, it caused a similar crash. If you'd like, you could share your minimal project setup with me so I can check it out and help determine if the problem is hardware-related.
